# TiXmlDocument::LoadFile for non-latin path names

Tags: utf-8, non-ascii-characters, tinyxml

I use tinyXml to store configuration file under FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, or in other words, under C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming.
I use the following sequence (simplified):

1. SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, 0, NULL, &path) to get the path
2. Encode path as UTF8
3. Call m_doc.LoadFile(path) // m_doc is TiXmlDocument object
4. call m_doc.Savefile() // This one fails if user name is non-latin

I wonder how I can LoadFile/SaveFile when the filename contains non-latin (e.g. Hebrew) characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no portable way to codify Windows filenames in `char`-based variables (C-strings or `std::string`s), since the Windows API does not accept the UTF8 encoding.

Luckily, TinyXml offers an alternative form of `LoadFile`, accepting a `FILE*` as argument. You can use the Windows `_wfopen` to get such handle: here is a snippet:

```
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, 0, NULL, &path);
FILE* xmlFile = _wfopen(path, L"r+");
m_doc.LoadFile(xmlFile);
```

The corresponding function `SaveFile` works in the same manner – in this case use `L"w"` as second parameter of the `_wfopen` call to overwrite the previous version of the file.